# C# Employee Manger Relationship in model class

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am  facing difficulty to solve a complex logic with C# LINQ

I have a Model class generated using core entity framework 3.1 :

```
   public partial class Employee
    {
        
        public int EmpId { get; set; }
        
        public string Fname { get; set; }
        
        public string Lname { get; set; }
        
        public string Emailid { get; set; }
        
        ublic int? ManagerId { get; set; }    //(self-referential integrity to employeeid)

        public varchar EmployeeDesignation { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a Action Method :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetEmployees()
        {      
        
            var employe = await _employee.GetEmployees();
            if (employe == null)
                return NotFound();
            else
            {
                    //Need a LINQ logic here 
                    
      
            }
        
        }
```

Logic need to achieve :

Initially EmployeeDesignation property will be empty  but with help of LINQ , I need to assign values based below 3 criteria

```
1. EmployeeDesignation  need be “Associate” when no other employee is reporting to this employee 
2. EmployeeDesignation  need be “Manager” when one or more employees are reporting to this employee
3. EmployeeDesignation  need be “Head” when one or more managers are reporting to this employee
```

So for each employeeid , The EmployeeDesignation  property need to be either Associate or Manager or Head based on the above 3 criteria's .

Excepted Output after LINQ logic:

```
employeeid :8
ftname : Tom
lName : Cru
emailid : Tomc@g.com
managerId: null
EmployeeDesignation: Associate

employeeid :9
fname : nee
lName : wili
emailid : nw@g.com
managerId: 3
EmployeeDesignation: Manager
```

How to achieve this by using LINQ,EF in c#?

Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Edits:

**Can refer below image**

[Please click the link to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWide.png)

Comment: Can you elaborate the "reporting" logic? Associate means managerId is null ? Manager means managerId is not null ? what about the Head ?

Comment: @AmenAyach Hi ,i have added new Link , hope it can help for better understanding.

Comment: Hi Neena, Why you are putting this logic in the `GetEmployee` method?!  Is `EmployeeDesignation` changed repetitively ?!

Comment: @HamedMoghadasi  Because GetEmployee loads a grid where i need to show employee , First ,Last name , Manager and Employee designation, Other details are available only Employee Designation need to worked out based on Manager ID Logic, Which i am missing and struck

Comment: I mean why you have not specified `Employee Designation` when you are persisting employee in the database ?!

Answer (score 0):

If I got u right:

```
private static string GetEmployeeDesignation(Employee employee, IEnumerable<Employee> employees)
{
    if (!employee.ManagerId.HasValue)
    {
        return "Head";
    }

    if (!employees.Any(m => m.ManagerId == employee.EmpId))
    {
        return "Associate";
    }

    return "Manager";
}
```

So your expected output might like:

```
var result = employees.Select(m =>
{
    m.EmployeeDesignation = GetEmployeeDesignation(m, employees);
    return m;
});
```